# ActiveMQ - delete/purge all queue via command line

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

Is there a way to delete / purge all queues in ActiveMQ via the command line (win/linux)?
I could only find the commands for a specific queue.
Or maybe there's a way to do this via the activeMQ admin? Again, I only found how to delete/purge the queues one by one, which can be very tedious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do tweak your `activemq.xml` a bit:

```
<broker deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="true"  ...>
```

This works with KahaDB message stores (it has problems with JDBC message stores), all your messages get deleted and subsequently queues are cleared.

As you want all queues to be deleted, restarting the broker won't be a costly option to clean everything up.

The purge will happen on 'every' restart

Answer (score 7):

I developed my own ActiveMQ command line utility (activemq-cli) to do this. You can find it here: https://github.com/antonwierenga/activemq-cli (command 'purge-all-queues' or 'remove-all-queues').

Answer (score 5):

As of version 5.0 it looks like this can be [done using the CLI provided with ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org/activemq-command-line-tools-reference.html) itself:

```
$ ActiveMQ/bin/activemq purge
```

Comment: `dequeueCount` is not updated to 0. Restarting after purge worked.

Answer (score 2):

1- go to amq bin folder, in my case:

```
cd /opt/amq/bin
```

2- run amq client:

```
./client
```

3- run purge on desired queue

```
activemq:purge <QUEUE NAME HERE>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to deploy a small Camel route in a container (e.g. Apache ServiceMix) or simply by executing a java program which contain the route.

For example here is the route I currently use on my development computer where I also have the ServiceMix installed:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.0.0" 
  xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
       http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd">

    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="amq.cleanup" update-strategy="reload">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="amq.local.url" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <onException useOriginalMessage="true">
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:CLEANUP_DLQ" />
        </onException>

        <route id="drop-all-queues" autoStartup="true">
            <from uri="activemq:queue:*.>" />
            <stop/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${amq.local.url}" />
    </bean>
</blueprint>
```