# How to destroy thousand of ActiveMQ queues on demand in short period of time?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel, activemq-classic

We are using thousand of queue to pass data inside the system. The problem which appears is that it takes always a lot of time to destroy it and also we have to wait until the queue is no longer used for sure.

To do that we curently use following approach

```
try {
  _consumer.getEndpoint().stop();
  _consumer.stop();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}

// Wait a little, so that ActiveMQ has time to realize that the endpoint is destroyed,
// which is necessary to be done before the queue is destroyed,
// otherwise we get an "Error: Destination still has an active subscription: queue://receive:XXX":

try {
  Thread.sleep(1);
}
catch (InterruptedException ex) {
  System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}

// Destroy queue:
String shortRxQueueName = _rxQueueName.replace("activemq:queue:", "");
try {
  activeMQConnection.destroyDestination(new ActiveMQQueue(shortRxQueueName));
}
catch (JMSException ex) {
  System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Even when we are trying to omit connection to broker and use just curently available `activeMQConnection` stoping 300 queues takes about 50 seconds.

```
3402: Stopping clients...
53500: Stopping camel context...
```

So, for each single destroying queue we consume 0.16s.

How to make it quicker? Does camel contains something like pool or cache queues to perform the actions?

Comment: do you have privilege to start/stop the server?

Comment: Yes. But in destination system the server should work continously. W want to limit number of queues to be ready for the new connections and release the resources.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this works for you according to your requirements, but you can have a look at this

[ActiveMQ - delete/purge all queue via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271276/activemq-delete-purge-all-queue-via-command-line)

what this does is, it deletes all queues and messages when activemq is started.

Hope this helps!
Good luck!